# Sitecore JSS support for http 2 and 3?

Tags: jss, http

Been working with Sitecore for a while now, `JSS` not quite as long, and `Headless` just recently. One thing I noticed the other day is that it appears all traffic coming from the `Node` front ends is being served via `HTTP v1.1`. I've looked and I see that `Node` itself does support `HTTP v2` at least, and I've found talk about it supporting `HTTP v3`, so I was wondering if there is some config I need to change, or if this is a forthcoming feature?
Thanks!

Comment: For Sitecore JSS and Headless, there might not be an out-of-the-box way to switch to HTTP/2 or HTTP/3. If you are self-hosting your Node.js server, you can adjust your server settings to use HTTP/2. If you are using PaaS provider or a hosting service, you might need to check with your provider on how to enable HTTP/2 or HTTP/3.